# ApiController doesn't receive my DateTime?

Tags: c#, jquery, json, controller, asp.net-web-api

My ApiController doesn't receive my `DateTime` object wrapped in a view model.

Here's my controller's contents.

```
public class FlowApiController : ApiController
{
    // GET api/flowapi
    public async Task<IEnumerable<FlowItemViewModel>> PostNewItems(SinceNullableViewModel input)
    {
        var since = input.Since; //since will be null for some reason

        ...

        return something;
    }
}
```

And then here's my jQuery AJAX call. I tried a number of different things, with no luck. This is what I have currently.

```
$.ajax("/api/FlowApi/NewItems", {
    method: "POST",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        Since: new Date()
    })
});
```

Finally, here's my `SinceNullableViewModel`.

```
public class SinceNullableViewModel
{
    public DateTime Since { get; set; }
}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Chrome sends the data as follows:

[image]

Comment: what happens when you change the Type of Since to String?

Comment: you are sending ajax request to `/api/FlowApi/NewItems` where as the endpoint you have shown in the question where you are expecting the value is `PostNewItems`... typo?

Comment: No Dakait. It's an ApiController.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are very close, just add one more header `contentType` to tell server that you are sending in JSON format:

```
$.ajax("/api/FlowApi/NewItems", {
    method: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({
        Since: new Date()
    })
});
```